# Add extra instances to my x_test and y_test after using train_test_split()

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification

I'm working on a multi-class classification problem in which I have my data categorized into 8 classes.

What I want to do is to extract out all the instances that are related to one classification from my training dataset and include in my testing dataset.

What I did until now is this:

```
# Generate some data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x2': np.random.normal(2, 3, 100),
    'x3': np.random.normal(4, 5, 100),
    'y': np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 100)})

df.head(10)


# Output is as follows
#         x1        x2        x3   y
# 0 -0.742347 -2.064889  2.979338  6
# 1  0.182298  6.366811  7.435432  7 <-- Instance no. 1 will be stored in (filtered_df) in the next step
# 2 -1.015937 -3.214670  8.544494  4
# 3  0.688138  1.938480  4.028213  6
# 4  0.397756  0.064590  9.186234  5
# 5  0.095368 -3.255433  1.010394  1
# 6  0.609087  6.783653  4.390600  6
# 7 -0.017803 -1.571393  6.539134  5
# 8  0.814820  4.535381  2.175285  0
# 9 -0.573918 -0.672416  0.826967  6



# Taking out instances that are classified as no "7" from the dataset
filtered_df = df[df['y']==7]
df.drop(df[df['y']==7].index, inplace=True)
df.head(10)

# Output is as follows
#          x1        x2        x3   y
# 0  -0.742347 -2.064889  2.979338  6
# 2  -1.015937 -3.214670  8.544494  4 <-- Instance no. 1 is stored in (filtered_df) now
# 3   0.688138  1.938480  4.028213  6
# 4   0.397756  0.064590  9.186234  5
# 5   0.095368 -3.255433  1.010394  1
# 6   0.609087  6.783653  4.390600  6
# 7  -0.017803 -1.571393  6.539134  5
# 8   0.814820  4.535381  2.175285  0
# 9  -0.573918 -0.672416  0.826967  6
# 11  0.044094  2.581373  1.368575  5

# Extract the features and target
X = df.iloc[:, 0:3]
y = df.iloc[:, 3]

# Spliting the dataset into train, test and validate for binary classification
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)

## Not sure how to add (filtered_df) to X_test and y_test now ?
```

I'm not sure how to continue further. How can I add the instances that are stored in `filtered_df` to `x_test` and `y_test` ?

Comment: Interesting. What is the use case?

Comment: It's a strange method. You have a training set with y between 0-6 and your testing set have only y = 7. How do you want to classify?

Comment: @jtlz2 I want to study how my model is going to classify some instnaces that it has not been trained on.

Comment: @Corralien I want my training dataset to include instances that are related to classes y=0 -> 6, and my testing dataset to include instances that are related to classes y= 0->7

Comment: @MohammedHadi. I posted an answer according to your comment. At each iteration, X_test and y_test contain a subset of your dataset (0.2) and the excluded class rather than X_train and y_train contain the other subset of your dataset (0.8) and nothing from the excluded class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
for klass in df['y'].unique():
    m = df['y'] != klass
    X = df.loc[m, df.columns[:3]]
    y = df.loc[m, df.columns[-1]]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)
    X_test = X_test.append(df.loc[~m, df.columns[:3]])
    y_test = y_test.append(df.loc[~m, df.columns[-1]])
    # do stuff here
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an answer, bit of a request for further info (can't comment yet).

If you just want to combine the dataframes,`.append()` is probably the way to go.

In your comments in the code block you say that you split the data set for binary classification but in the description of the problem you mention multi-class classification.

Two ways to approach this the way I see it:

- either as a full on multi-class classification (in which case you shouldn't need to separate just one class for some reason) using a model that inherently supports multiple classes, or
- a series of binary classifiers with the aim of ensembling them later (where you should create copies of the dataset for first class vs all, second class vs all etc., but sklearn already handles that with [`sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier)). You could then get probabilities from each of the models (if they are supported) and pick your final predicted class with the largest probability.

Just in case you haven't came across it already, maybe worth having a look in [sklearn's "Multiclass and multioutput algorithms" page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).

Comment: The binary part was a mistake from my side as I was copying and pasting some repetitive code without realizing.  However, I didn't know about `sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier` ,  and I think it might help me out in the future. So, thanks for your help.